# Error when trying to emphasize multiple rows using pandoc.table

Tags: r, pander

I am having an odd problem when it comes to emphasizing multiple rows in a table using pandoc.table.  Specifically, the values in the table seem to be filled in inappropriately when more than 1 row is specified.  For example, if I do not emphasize a row or only emphasize 1 row

```
library(pander)
A <- matrix(1:25, nrow=5)
pandoc.table(A)
```

---

1 6  11 16 21

2 7  12 17 22

3 8  13 18 23

4 9  14 19 24

5 10 15 20 25

---

```
bold <- c(4)

pandoc.table(A, emphasize.strong.rows=bold)
```

---

1     6     11     16     21

2     7     12     17     22

3     8     13     18     23

**4** **9** **14** **19** **24**

5    10     15     20     25

---

everything works beautifully, but when I specify multiple rows, the bolding occurs on the correct rows but the wrong values are placed in the cells

```
bold <- c(2, 4)

pandoc.table(A, emphasize.strong.rows=bold)
```

---

1     6      11     16     21

**2** **12** **22** **9**  **19**

3     8      13     18     23

**7** **17** **4**  **14** **24**

5     10     15     20     25

---

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Robert

R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] pander_0.5.2     HTGPackage_0.0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.1  Rcpp_0.12.0  digest_0.6.8

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a known bug in the CRAN version of the package, but was already [fixed](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/pull/177) in the [development version of pander](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander#installation). Should be on CRAN in a few weeks.

Comment: Thank you.  I love the package and look forward to the update.